# Как проверить действительные ожидаемые значения с помощью таблицы ASCII в C ++?

Tags: c++

В настоящее время я пытаюсь получить правильные цифры только для пользовательского ввода и хочу, чтобы сообщение об ошибке указывало неправильное значение, если пользовательский ввод недопустим, но у меня возникла небольшая проблема с достижением цели. Вы можете проверить мой код, если это возможно сделать так, как я ожидаю от своего кода.

Когда пользовательский ввод 123456789, вывод должен быть:

> Введенный номер 123456789  правильный

Когда пользовательский ввод 1234k1234, вывод должен быть:

> Введенное вами число 1234k недопустимо и содержит недопустимый символ (k).

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void Welcome();
bool isNumber (string tmp);
int main ()
{
Beginning:
    Welcome();
string tmp;
cout << "Введите число: " << '\n';
cin >> tmp;

    if (isNumber (tmp) )
        {
        cout << " Введенный вами номер правильный" << '\n';
        goto Beginning;
    }
    else
            cout << " Введенный вами номер недействителен и содержит недопустимый символ" << '\n';
            goto Beginning;
}
void Welcome()
{
    cout << "Добро пожаловать в программу" << '\n';
}
bool isNumber (string tmp)
{
if (tmp [0] == '0')
    return false;
for (int i = 0; i < tmp.length () && isNumber; i++ )
{
    cout << tmp [i];
    if (!(tmp [i] >= 48 && tmp [i] <= 57))
    return false;
}
    return true;
    }
```

Comment: main()... может int main() ??. goto НИКОГДА НЕ ЮЗАЙ!!

Comment: @ДанилПерелыгин Это не важно, мой GCC справиться с этим

Comment: @ДанилПерелыгин goto - это функция, указывающая начало, чтобы начать снова, когда необходимо

Comment: `goto` - это оператор и его лучше избегать, используйте `for`/`while` и `break`/`continue` вместо него. И точно нужно зациклить, когда ввод правильный? может наоборот, повторять пока неверный ввод?

Comment: @DrawnRaccoon да, я исправил это, и все же мне нравится использовать goto

Comment: А мне нравится кушать сладкое, только вот для зубов вредно...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы почти всё дописали. Осталось просто вывести на экран. Я чуток подправил предупреждения компилятора.

```
// g++ -Wall -std=c++11 printchar.cpp -o printchar
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

// warning: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘main’ with no type
int main ( )
{
Beginning:
    string tmp;
    cout << "Введите число: " << '\n';
    cin >> tmp;
    bool isNumber = true;
    unsigned int bad_index = 0 ;
    if (tmp [0] == '0')
        isNumber = false;

    // warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < tmp.length () && isNumber; i++ )
    {
        // в Си буквы и числа почти тоже самое. '0' равно 48
        if (!(tmp [i] >= '0' && tmp [i] <= '9'))
        {
            isNumber = false;
            bad_index = i ;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (isNumber)
    {
        cout << " Введенный вами номер " << tmp << " правильный" << '\n';
        goto Beginning;
    }
    else
        cout << " Введенный вами номер " << tmp << " недействителен и содержит недопустимый символ '" << tmp [ bad_index ] << "'\n";

}
```

Comment: работает отлично.
Но почему это не должно быть, 
if (! (Tmp [i]> = '48' && tmp [i] <= '57'))
строка содержит символы в таблице ASCII от 48 до 57

Comment: Прога понятнее читается.

Comment: хм теперь все ясно

Comment: А прямая логика `if (tmp[i] < '0' || tmp[i] > '9') { isNumber = false; ... }` еще понятнее читается

Comment: @avp это не важно && в то же время использовать?

Comment: @Саша, не понял, что вы имеете в виду. Значения выражений `(tmp[i] < '0' || tmp[i] > '9')` и `(! (tmp[i] >= 48 && tmp[i] <= 57))` для кодов символов ASCII одинаковы.  Просто в первом случае явно проверяется вхождение кода символа  в диапазон кодов до цифр (от 0 до 9) или в диапазон после цифр, а во втором, вхождение в диапазон цифр, с последующей инверсией. Это называется *инверсивная логика*, которая считается более сложной для восприятия большинством людей, поэтому ее советуют избегать при написании алгоритмов/программ

Comment: @avp ага, но для меня эта обратная логика очень проста, и я не делаю упора на это, и if (! (tmp [i]> = 48 && tmp [i] <= 57)) вернуть false; или isNumber = false; возвращает противоположность (! (tmp [i]> = 48 && tmp [i] <= 57)), потому что мы уже используем отрицание и соединение в то же время

Comment: @avp я не привык к такой логике. Расписывать, что нельзя меньше, нельзя больше, нельзя комплексный числа и т.д. приводит к большой нагрузке на мозг и боишься, ничто не пропустил? А задание чёткого диапазона намного понятнее. Как вам такой пример? `if(tmp [i] >= '0' && tmp [i] <= '9'){}else{..ошибка..}`

Comment: @AlexGlebe, на самом деле тут надо писать `if (!isdigit(tmp[i])) { ... }`, (кстати, [isdigit](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/isdigit.3p.html) это стандарная функция) упрятывая конкретные проверки

Answer (score 1):

```
int main() {
    string s;
    while (true) {
        int pos = -1;
        cin >> s;
        if (s.empty()) {
            cout << "Строка пустая" << endl;
        } else if (s[0] == '0') {
            cout << "Лидирующий 0" << endl;
        } else if (!all_of(s.begin(), s.end(), [&pos](unsigned char c) { ++pos; return isdigit(c); })) {
            cout << "Введенное вами число " << s.substr(0, pos + 1) << " недопустимо и содержит недопустимый символ (" << s[pos] << ")" << endl;
        } else {
            cout << "Введенный вами номер " << s << " правильный" << endl;
            break;
        }
    }
    // ...
}
```

Comment: else if (!all_of(s.begin(), s.end(), [&pos](unsigned char c) { ++pos; return isdigit(c); }))   all_of не объявлено

Comment: `#include <algorithm>`

Comment: Racoon, Да, сейчас работает, но я не могу включить алгоритм, я новичок, сегодня мой 5-й день практики с ++

Comment: @Саша Ну это же не первый ваш ЯП, тем более после Java, зачем себя ограничивать, функции высших порядков и лямда-функции есть и в Java

Comment: Я начинающий C ++, а не Java, я не нашел Java полезным.
Я разработчик игр, и мне кажется, что C ++ лучше для меня.
Я потратил время на Java

Comment: @Саша "Я разработчик игр" - громко учитывая код из вопроса)

Comment: @Maggot так е нада :P

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно проверить, работает ли калькулятор.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    string iNum;
    cout << "Введите любой номер, чтобы запустить калькулятор! Латинские символы запрещены" << '\n';
    cin >> iNum;
    bool iNumvalidation = true;
    int bad_inputValidation = 0;
    if (iNum [0] == '0')
        iNumvalidation = false;
    for (int iNumvalidationVerify = 0; iNumvalidationVerify < iNum.length() && iNumvalidation; iNumvalidationVerify++)
    {
        if (!(iNum [iNumvalidationVerify] >='0' && iNum [iNumvalidationVerify] <= '9'))
          {
                iNumvalidation = false;
                bad_inputValidation = iNumvalidationVerify;
                break;
          }
    }
        if (iNumvalidation)
         {
             cout << "---------------------" << '\n';
             cout << "Калькулятор запущен" << '\n';
             cout << "---------------------" << '\n';
             int a,b;
cout << "Введите первое значение" << endl;
cin >> a;
cout << "Введите второе значение" << endl;
cin >> b;

cout << "Пожалуйста, выберите, что вы хотите сделать" << endl;
cout << " + " << endl;
cout << " - " << endl;
cout << " * " << endl;
cout << " / " << endl;

char desision;
cout << "Выберите решение: " << endl;
cin >> desision;
switch (desision)
    {
        case '+':
        cout << "Сумма " << a << " + " << b << " = " << (a+b) << endl;
        break;
        case '-':
        cout << "Вычитание " << a << " - " << b << " = " << (a-b) << endl;
        break;
        case '*':
        cout << "Умножение " << a << " * " << b << " = " << (a*b) << endl;
        break;
        case '/':
            if (b == !0)
            cout << "Отдел " << a << " / " << b << " = " << (a/b) << endl;
                else
                cout << "Невозможно разделить на ноль, попробуйте еще раз" << endl;
                return 0;
         }
         }

             else
            cout << "Неверный ввод: " << "[" << iNum [bad_inputValidation] << "]" << " не является числом и принадлежит [ABCD ...] и это не разрешено. Попробуйте еще раз" << '\n';
}
```